# Trouble with jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have used jScrollPane on my site. I'm also using ajax to update the data on the same div where the jScrollPane is used. Now, when i append the returned data to the div, the scrollbar is not visible on the appended text. It may because the jQuery function is called when the document loads but now any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the auto reinitialise function in jScrollPane when inserting content dynamicly, something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true, showArrows:true, scrollbarWidth: 16, arrowSize: 15});
});
```

Comment: can you look at my code and tell what do i need to do. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621048/jscrollpane-trouble